# Selecting an element that has a specific class and ID

Tags: css

I tried this and it worked in all browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari):

.classname#id

Still, I can't find this mentioned anywhere on w3c.org, can you point me to where this is mentioned? I mean if this is supported by all those browsers then it must be part of the standard, isn't it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain CSS selectors, it's just like using H1.title where you chain a type selector (H1) and a class selector (.title).
See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selector-syntax

Comment: It's in the css syntax at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#appendix-b - interestingly it seems to require that the id comes before the class (one the of the alternatives for 'simple_selector' is 'solitary_id class? pseudo_class?', the question marks mean that the class and pseudo_class are optional).

Comment: I can't find that syntax or any example that has an id with a class chained together, so it seems they don't mention all possible combinations

Comment: Standards usually don't list all possible combinations, at that would result in a much larger document (in many cases an infinitely large one). The syntax allows for this combination and the meaning is defined, and that's enough.

Comment: Also, you don't have to always refer to the standards, for most people secondary sources (such as a good text book or reference site) is good enough. And often better as they can discuss relevant information that doesn't belong in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

It is useless though, only specifying the ID would be enough.

```
#id
```

...unless you tried to be clever and used an identifier for more than one element.

Comment: There is a use. You might be using the same CSS on multiple pages - on some pages the element with that id has the class, on others it doesn't.

Comment: Right, didn't think of that. Though I would chain in the other order: #id.class

Comment: I'll tell you why I need this. I'm using a suckerfish menu on my site, you know that IE6 supports the hover pseudo-class only on links, suckerfish adds a little javascript to handle this for IE6 (adds a class in onmouseover and removes it in onmouseout), I'm trying the style the first level of LIs, I have two links in the first level with each one having different styles, also every one having different styles when hovered on, so I want something like this: .sfhover#firstmenuitem and .sfhover#secondmenuitem